# How to append different length columns to a different pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am downloading stock prices dataframe and I want to take one column from the stock prices dataframe and copy it to another dataframe.

```
Stock Prices Dataframe (MCD):

          Date    Open    High     Low   Close  Adjusted_close   Volume
    0   2020-01-06  199.60  202.77  199.35  202.33        185.6859  4660400
    1   2020-01-07  201.87  202.68  200.51  202.63        185.9612  4047400
    2   2020-01-08  202.62  206.69  202.20  205.91        188.9714  5284200
    3   2020-01-09  206.86  209.37  206.10  208.35        191.2107  5971600
    4   2020-01-10  208.44  208.95  207.27  207.27        190.2195  2336400
    5   2020-01-13  207.38  207.78  205.76  206.51        189.5221  2784200
    6   2020-01-14  205.46  207.65  205.46  207.32        190.2654  2622700
    7   2020-01-15  207.32  210.35  207.32  209.77        192.5139  3369400

Stock Prices Dataframe (AAPL):

         Date     Open      High      Low   Close  Adjusted_close     Volume
    0  2020-01-06  293.790  299.9600  292.750  299.80         73.1149  118578564
    1  2020-01-07  299.840  300.9000  297.480  298.39         72.7710  111510640
    2  2020-01-08  297.160  304.4399  297.156  303.19         73.9416  132363796
    3  2020-01-09  307.235  310.4300  306.200  309.63         75.5122  170486156
    4  2020-01-10  310.600  312.6700  308.250  310.33         75.6829  140869092

Stock Prices Dataframe (TXN):

         Date    Open    High     Low   Close  Adjusted_close   Volume
    0  2020-01-06  127.06  127.33  125.90  126.96        113.6177  4345400
    1  2020-01-07  129.15  130.90  128.42  129.41        115.8102  7184100
    2  2020-01-08  129.34  130.57  129.06  129.76        116.1235  3546900
    3  2020-01-09  130.70  131.74  130.24  131.33        117.5285  3526600
    4  2020-01-10  131.81  131.81  129.82  130.00        116.3382  3234000
    5  2020-01-13  130.57  130.74  129.77  129.95        116.2935  4313200
    6  2020-01-14  129.95  131.86  129.83  130.67        116.9378  4626200
    7  2020-01-15  130.43  130.43  128.86  129.17        115.5955  3392300
    8  2020-01-16  130.00  130.23  129.35  130.16        116.4814  5475900
    9  2020-01-17  130.76  132.04  130.44  131.70        117.8596  5487100
```

What I will do is download each dataframe individually and then choose the Adjusted Close column and copy it to another dataframe (I am doing this for 50 companies).

Code:

```
import csv

# Retreive symbols from Stocks CSV file and put them into one list

symbols = []
symbol_errors = []

try:
    with open('stocks.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
        for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
            symbols.append(row[0])
except:
    print("File Not Found")
    
# Create portfolio dataframe with symbols as column names
portfolio = pd.DataFrame(columns=symbols)

# Split the url into a beginning url and ending url
url_begin = 'someurl'
url_end ='someurl'

'''
1) Loop on the Symbols List.
2) Append the Symbol to the beginning and ending url.
3) Check if the data is retreived, if not append unfound symbols
    to error list.
4) Copy the adjusted data column to the corresponding symbol in
    the portfolio dataframe.
'''
for i in range(len(symbols)):
    url = url_begin+symbols[i]+url_end
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(url)
    except:
        symbol_errors.append(symbols[i])
    
    portfolio[symbols[i]] = data.iloc[:, 5:6]
```

When I execute the above code I get the following error:

```
for i in range(len(symbols)):
    url = url_begin+symbols[i]+url_end
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(url)
    except:
        symbol_errors.append(symbols[i])

    portfolio[symbols[i]] = data.iloc[:, 5:6]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[6], line 8
    portfolio[symbols[i]] = data.iloc[:, 5:6]

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3940 in 
__setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4069 in 
_set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate your error exactly, but using `pd.concat` is a better solution.

For example in your current solution, if the first symbol has the smallest number of rows, all the other columns will be truncated to the same length (i.e. you'll lose data).

See `pd.concat` implementation using some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n = 3
symbols = list(range(n))
ranges = [5,6,7]
dfs = [] # blank list
for i in range(n):
    # generate dummy data
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Adjusted Close': np.random.random(ranges[i])})
    dfs.append(df.iloc[:, 0:1])
    
dfs = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
dfs.columns = symbols
print(dfs)
```

output:

```
          0         1         2
0  0.126367  0.011863  0.441322
1  0.952424  0.201490  0.973999
2  0.682131  0.472226  0.762176
3  0.012474  0.971862  0.564928
4  0.995625  0.272742  0.273181
5       NaN  0.711388  0.433897
6       NaN       NaN  0.503719
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your questions correctly you're trying to have the close price of each stock in your portfolio, all in a one data frame.

Assuming that you're okay reading the stock prices from Yahoo finance and not from csv files here is an example showing how to do it:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

symbols = ["MDC", "AAPL", "TXN"]

portfolio = pd.DataFrame(columns=symbols)

for symbol in symbols:
    ticker = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
    stock = ticker.history()
    close = stock["Close"]
    portfolio[symbol] = close

portfolio.head()
```

The output would be something like
[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thary.png)

Comment: I am using EODHD api. I get a CSV file that I read with pandas read_csv function. And yes I want the output the same as the image you have posted. The thing is that I get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Mahmood, regardless where are you reading the prices from. I think the important part for you is the for loop, specifically this line: ` portfolio[symbol] = close`

Comment: Hi @MahmoudAbdel-Rahman, Did it help?

Comment: I figured out the problem in my code. Some ticker symbols didn't exist that is why the program was giving me a ValueError. I added an exception handling in order for the program not to stop when an error occurs. Thanks for your code.